# Firebase Functions create multiple documents in one function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I would like to create few documents when new user is created. I understand I can create a separate function for every document, but I would like to put all of them in one function.

Example code for one document (functions/index.js):

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createWHS = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  const docData = {
    name: "myWHS",
    description: "My Awesome Warehouse",
    created: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    image: "",
    color: "#008080",
  };

  return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid)
      .collection("warehouses").doc("myWHS").set(docData);
});
```

Are there batch writes as well?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create multiple documents, you can use `Promise.all` to wait for all of those to be finished before finishing the function. Something like this:

```
return Promise.all([
  admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid)
                   .collection("warehouses").doc("myWHS").set(docData),
  admin.firestore().collection("othercolection").add(docData)
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do batch writes on firestore see [Batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes)

Comment: Hi, I didn't ask for Firestore batch writes. I asked for Firebase functions batch writes

Comment: What is `firebase functions batch writes`? You are writing data to firestore via admin sdk, Still is `Firestore batch writes`.